# Is there such a thing as an array without size?

Tags: c#, arrays

I am playing with C#. I try to write program that frames the quote entered by a user in a square of chars. So, the problem is... a user needs to indicate the number of lines before entering a quote. I want to remove this moment, so the user just enters lines of their phrase (each line is a new element in the string array, so I guess a program should kinda declare it by itself?..). I hope I explained clear what I meant x).

I've attached the program code below. I know that it is not perfect (for example, when entering the number of lines, I use the conversion to an integer, and if a user enters a letter, then this may confuse my electronic friend, this is a temporary solution, since I do not want to ask this x) The program itself must count these lines! x)) Though, I don't understand why the symbols on the left side are displayed incorrectly when the program displays output, but I think this also does not matter yet).

```
        //Greet a user, asking for the number of lines.
        Console.WriteLine("Greetings! I can put any phrase into beautiful @-square."
            + "\n" + "Wanna try? How many lines in the quote: ");
        int numberOfLines = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        //Asking for each line.
        string[] lines = new string[numberOfLines];
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfLines; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the line: ");
            lines[i] = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        //Looking for the biggest line
        int length = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfLines; i++)
        {
            if (length < lines[i].Length) length = lines[i].Length;
        }

        //Starting framing
        char doggy = '@';
        char space = ' ';
        length += 4;
        string frame = new String(doggy, length);

        Console.WriteLine(frame);
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfLines; i++)
        {
            string result = new string(space, length - 3 - lines[i].Length);
            Console.WriteLine(doggy + space + lines[i] + result + doggy);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(frame);

        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Use a `List<T>` instead.

Comment: Aside from using a list, it's not clear what you're asking at the moment. I don't see anywhere that your question body refers to "an array without a size" - and we don't know what output you're *actually* getting and what you *expected* to get. ("I don't understand why the symbols on the left side are displayed incorrectly" doesn't tell us either of these things.) Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ and edit your question to clarify it.

Comment: List<T> is simpler and more flexible than array, so it will solve at least the problem of needeng to know the final/maximum length of the array.

Answer (score 0):

There is performance gap and functionality between "[Generic Lists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0)" and arrays, you can read more about cons and pros of this two objects in the internet,

for example you can use list as Dai mentioned in comment like this

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add("one");
list.Add("two");
list.Add("three");
```

or you can use arraylist

```
ArrayList arraylist = new ArrayList();
arraylist.Add();
```

or even you can change the size of array any times but it erase data in it

```
int[] arr = new int[100];
```

there is a function called ToArray() you can use it to change generic list to array

Comment: There is no legitimate reason to use `ArrayList` today - not at any point since .NET Framework 2.0 in 2005. It should be removed from .NET entirely, imo.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem of the left side output is, that you add two values of char. This is not what you expect to be. You must convert the char to a string to append it to other strings:

```
Console.WriteLine(doggy.ToString() + space.ToString() + lines[i] + result + doggy.ToString());
```